# How to transpose repeating groups in excel?

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet with the following data structure

```
+-------------+-------------------------------+--+
| title       | Dr.                           |  |
| first_name  | Adam                          |  |
| last_name   | Meyer                         |  |
| email       | adam.meyer@my-company.com     |  |
| phone       | +49 (0)931-32187-0            |  |
| fax         |                               |  |
| room        |                               |  |
| position    | Direktor                      |  |
| title       |                               |  |
| first_name  | Judith                        |  |
| last_name   | Schmidt                       |  |
| email       | judith.schmidt@my-company.com |  |
| phone       |  +49 (0)444-32131-1           |  |
| fax         |                               |  |
| room        |                               |  |
| position    |                               |  |
| title       |                               |  |
| first_name  | Claus                         |  |
| last_name   | Niemes                        |  |
| email       |  claus.niemes@my-company.com  |  |
| phone       |  +49 (0)444-32131-2           |  |
| fax         |                               |  |
| room        |                               |  |
| position    | Verkäufer                     |  |
| bio         | xxxxxxxxxx                    |  |
| title       | Dr.                           |  |
| first_name  | András                        |  |
| last_name   | Cloon                         |  |
| email       | andrás.cloon@my-company.de    |  |
| phone       | +49 (0)444-32131-1            |  |
+-------------+-------------------------------+--+
```

Not all 450 Persons have values for all rows. Sometimes is missing the first row with the title for example.

I want to import these data into a mysql database.

I need this result:
[image]

I'm not an excel expert that's why I'm happy about every hint how to ease the preparation of the data for the import.

I know how to do the import.

Comment: Copy, paste special transpose to turn it into a table with column headings and data in rows

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide sample data that includes the Column 1 & 2?

Comment: @Birel I have added sample data. Until now I just cleaned the data.

Comment: @HarassedDad When using transpose I get a lot of columns with the same label i.e. hfm_person_first_name.

Comment: How could you get a lot of columns with `hfm_person_first_name` after a transpose when you only have a single row here with that value? Please share a better representative sample of your data AND your desired results after this transformation you are needing help with occurs. Please copy your data from excel and paste it into https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ Choosing "Header Location" "Spreadsheet" then copy and paste here into your question (both your fixed sample and your desired results). Highlight what you pasted and hit the code button at the top of the editor `{}`.

Comment: My data are only an example for 2 Persons. In total I have about 450 people. Since the data have a private character, I would have to invent fictitious persons for the example table.

Comment: I extended my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh I see what you want now

```
     Sub SortItOUt()
    Dim t As Range
    Dim r As Range
    Set t = Sheets(2).Range("a2") 'I assume a blank second sheet to collect the data
    Set r = Sheets(1).Range("a1") 'assume data starts in sheet 1
    Do
      Dim x As Long
      For x = 0 To 7
          r.Offset(x, 1).Copy t.Offset(0, x) 'copy and transpose
      Next x
      Set t = t.Offset(1, 0)
      Set r = r.Offset(8, 0)

     Loop Until r = ""
  End Sub
```

Comment: I think my data is too unstructured. After a person with only for rows the following column entries are all mixed up. I extended the example in my question. The problem is the person 'Mr. Cloon'.

Comment: I have accepted your answer as it works in principle. Thank you very much for that.